# Java stream classes : How to make a win zip Application

Tags: java

I want to make a win zip software. I am reading `java stream classes` and `zip class` but my mind can't work in this topic. Please help me How to do this. This my minor project in my college. I made two project in java.

1. Library management System
2. Diagnostic Lab Management

But Teacher say Management project not allowed. Please help me

This code work in one directory make for multidirectory

My Program Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class MyZip{
    FileInputStream fis;
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    ZipOutputStream zout;
    ZipEntry ze;

    public MyZip()throws IOException{
        Console con=System.console();

        System.out.println("How many directories do u want to compressed:");
        int no_file=Integer.parseInt(con.readLine());
        String inputFile[]=new String[no_file];
        File fileArray[]=new File[no_file];
        System.out.println("Enter the path of directories to be compressed:");
        for(int i=0;i<inputFile.length;i++){
            inputFile[i]=con.readLine();
            fileArray[i]=new File(inputFile[i]);
        }


        String outputFile="E:\\MyProgram\\MyZip\\MyZip.zip";
        fos=new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        zout=new ZipOutputStream(bos);
        zipFile(fileArray);
        zout.close();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
        getZipEntry();
    }
    public void getZipEntry()throws IOException{
        ZipFile zf=new ZipFile("E:\\MyProgram\\MyZip\\MyZip.zip");
        System.out.println(zf.getName());//return name of zip file
        Enumeration e=zf.entries();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()){
            ZipEntry ze=(ZipEntry)e.nextElement();
            System.out.print(ze.getName()+"\t");//return name of entry
            System.out.print(ze.getSize()+"\t");//return uncompressed size
            System.out.print(ze.getCompressedSize());//return compressed size
            System.out.println();
        }
        zf.close();
    }
    public void zipFile(File farr[])throws IOException{
        for(File f:farr){
            if(f.isFile()){
                writeFile(f);
            }
            if(f.isDirectory()){
                File fileArray[]=f.listFiles();
                zipFile(fileArray);
            }
        }
    }
    public void writeFile(File f)throws IOException{
        ze=new ZipEntry(f.getPath());
        zout.putNextEntry(ze);
        fis=new FileInputStream(f);
        bis=new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        int ch;
        while((ch=bis.read())!=-1)
            zout.write(ch);

        bis.close();
        fis.close();
        zout.closeEntry();
        zout.flush();   

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        new MyZip();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you did till now?? Show your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for unzip your code only for zip

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
class MyUnZip
{
    FileInputStream fis;
    BufferedInputStream bis;
    ZipInputStream zis;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    public MyUnZip(String inputFile)throws IOException{
        String path1=inputFile.substring(0,inputFile.lastIndexOf('.'));
        //System.out.println(path1);

        fis=new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        bis=new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        zis=new ZipInputStream(bis);

        File outputFile;
        ZipEntry ze=null;

        while((ze=zis.getNextEntry())!=null){
            String str=ze.getName();
            //System.out.println(str);
            File fileName=new File(str);

            String path2=str.substring(str.indexOf('\\'),str.lastIndexOf('\\'));
            //System.out.println(path2);

            String path3=path1+path2;
            System.out.println(path3);

            File filePath=new File(path3);
            filePath.mkdirs();
            outputFile=new File(path3,fileName.getName());
            fos=new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            int ch;
            while((ch=zis.read())!=-1)
                bos.write(ch);
            bos.close();
            fos.close();
            zis.closeEntry();
        }
        zis.close();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Console con=System.console();
        System.out.println("Enter the path of zip file to be uncompressed:");
        String inputFile=con.readLine();
        new MyUnZip(inputFile);
    }
}
```